# ImageButton with PostBackUrl responds after the second click issue

Tags: asp.net

Hello i have a problem with my Imagebutton i have to double click just to get it to post any one know how i can fix it so i only have to click it once to get a response?

thank you for your help!

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smokeshopConnectionString %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:smokeshopConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID, Name, Description, Price, ImageUrl FROM products"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"         
         DataKeyField="ProductID"   >
        <ItemTemplate>        
                <div style="border-style:dotted; border-color:WhiteSmoke;">                    
                <a onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" href="#" ><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl", "Images\\{0}") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("ProductID", "Default5.aspx?ProductID={0}") %>' /></a><br />       

                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label><br />               
                </div>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: do you really want cross page postback? or want to navigate to details page when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I have test code from side ..its works fine ..I got image button event in single click.  I think problem is with javascript function written over imagebutton i.e.

```
popup('popUpDiv')
```

Can you please explain javascript function "popup('popUpDiv')" .. or you can test it with remove anchor link tag from image button..

Comment: its a popup div that display a second datalist